# ValueError: activation is not a legal parameter

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network

I'm trying to tune my model but I'm getting this Value Error. I tried to change the activation function, but when I did the learning rate returned the same error. I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

```
>ValueError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

> <ipython-input-46-5d07e2ad456a> in <module>
>      9   param_distributions = params,
>     10   cv = KFold(10))

> --->11 random_search_results = random_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

ValueError: activation is not a legal parameter
```

```
def create_model(learning_rate=0.01):
    opt = 'Adam'
    Tuning_model = Sequential()
    Tuning_model.add(Dense(16, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
    Tuning_model.add(Dropout(.2))
    Tuning_model.add(BatchNormalization())
    Tuning_model.add(Activation('relu'))
    Tuning_model.add(Dense(32))
    Tuning_model.add(Dropout(.2))
    Tuning_model.add(Dense(1))
    Tuning_model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt, metrics='mse')
    
    return Tuning_model
```

```
# Define the hyperparameter space
params = {'activation': ["relu", "tanh"],
          'batch_size': [16, 32, 64, 128], 
          'epochs': [50, 100],
          'optimizer': ["Adam", "SGD", "RMSprop"],
          'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.001, 0.0001]}
# Create a randomize search cv object 
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(Tuning_model,
                                   param_distributions = params,
                                   cv = KFold(10))
random_search_results = random_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Can you post the entire code which caused this error?

Answer (score 4):

The ValueError is raised because `activation` is not a parameter of the whole model, but rather a parameter of certain of its' layer(s). So when `RandomizedSearchCV` tries to pass it, `Model` object can't accept it.

I suggest 2 solutions:

1. use `KerasClassifier` [wrapper](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn/KerasClassifier) around build function and make activation one of its. Then optimize its performance with RandomizedSearchCV.

2. Use a dedicated optimization package, like `optuna` - it works smarter and has greater degree of customization. Try it - they have good and easy docs on [their site](https://optuna.org/).

Side note: RandomizedSearchCV with 10 folds is an overkill, if sample is large enough, make it 2 or even single fold.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. This is a regression problem that's why I'm using Keras regressor. I will try optuna and decrease the number of folds.